# Countdown starting at random negative number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, invoke

My countdown timer in ShowRestartDialog() is acting funky. Instead of starting at the defined countdownLength (which is set to 5) it is starting at a random negative number and going down from there. Why would that be happening? Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static CountdownTimer countdownTimerInstance = null; // Create Singleton

    public Object startingScene;
    public GameObject timeOutWarningDialog;
    private GameObject timerDialogBoxInstance;
    private GameObject canvas; 

    private IEnumerator counter;
    private Button stopCountButton;
    private Text timerTextField;

    public float countdownLength;
    public float countdownDelay;
    private float countdownInterval = 1.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (countdownTimerInstance == null)
            countdownTimerInstance = this;
        else if (countdownTimerInstance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    public void StartPreCountTimer()
    {
        GameManager.preCountActive = true;

        Debug.Log("StartPreCountTimer Timer has Started!");

        if (GameManager.restartWarningActive == false)
            Invoke("ShowRestartDialog", countdownDelay);
    }

    public void RestartPreCountTimer()
    {
        GameManager.preCountActive = false;

        Debug.Log("StartPreCountTimer Timer has Restarted!");
            CancelInvoke("ShowRestartDialog");
    }

    void ShowRestartDialog()
    {
        GameManager.preCountActive = false;

        canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");

        timerDialogBoxInstance = Instantiate(timeOutWarningDialog); // instantiate timeout warning dialog
        timerDialogBoxInstance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        timerDialogBoxInstance.SetActive(true);

        Text[] textFields = timerDialogBoxInstance.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>(true); // get reference to timer textfields
        timerTextField = textFields[2]; // access and assign countdown textfield

        stopCountButton = timerDialogBoxInstance.GetComponentInChildren<Button>(); // get reference to keep playing button
        stopCountButton.onClick.AddListener(StopDialogTimer); // add button listener

        if (timerDialogBoxInstance.activeInHierarchy == true)
            InvokeRepeating("StartDialogTimer", 0, countdownInterval);
    }

    void StartDialogTimer()
    {
        float s = countdownLength--;

        Debug.Log(s);

        if (timerTextField != null)
            timerTextField.text = s.ToString();

        if (s == -1)
        {
            RestartGame();
        }
    }

    void StopDialogTimer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Restart Cancelled");
        CancelInvoke("StartDialogTimer");
        Destroy(timerDialogBoxInstance);
    }

    void RestartGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(startingScene.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: "countdownLength (which is set to 5)"  -- is not true in your code.  You do not initialize it. Therefore it's set to 0.

Comment: I don't even see the literal `5` _anywhere_ in the code you posted. If you want help, post a good [mcve] that actually reproduces the behavior you claim is happening. The code above isn't minimal, nor does it actually do what you claim it does.

Comment: It is not random. With the game timer starts too and counting backwards in every seconds.

Comment: What are you 3 talking about? This is Unity, he can set values of public variables in inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize bad your s variable.
    float s = countdownLength--;

On declaration s = 0.0f - 5 ===> -5 first value

You never reach the -1 value to restart your game. 
A way to reach is changing this:

```
if (s <= -1)
{
    RestartGame();
}
```